# p:dataTable, p:contextMenu and p:poll in PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

I'd like resolve a little conflict...

Let me explain...

I have one `<p:dataTable>`, one `<p:poll>` and one `<p:contextMenu>` for the dataTable... Every 6 seconds this poll update the dataTable.

When I click on dataTable to show the contextMenu and I await a little, when the poll updates the dataTable this contextMenu close and I lose my reference of the selected object.

I saw and put the event 'contextMenu' in dataTable, so every time when I open the contextMenu this event is triggered then I have the possibility to stop the poll, but I don't have how to start it again. ( if I click in some menuItem, ok I could start it again, but If not?)

Any ideas??

Comment: Since the context menu is bound to the data table which  in turn, is updated on every 6 seconds, the context menu has to be bound once again - once an update is made. So, what do you expect or is required? Do you want to pause the `<p:poll>` while a user is interacting with the data table/context menu and resume it later on as and when the user wishes?

Comment: you can with some investigation (examples are on the internet, I'm typing  on my mobile phone) override the javascript hide function in the overlay.js. Then you can start polling again on the 'onHide'

Comment: @Tiny I want to what my users can use this function without problems, because if they open the context menu, for example when the <p:poll> counter is at 4s, then they'll have just 2s to press some <p:menuItem>.

Comment: @Kukeltje javascript and override those methods are my weak points... Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, no, workarounds of that kind fall beyond the time I'd like to invest in spending helping others.  But google is your friend and if there are specific details that do not work, I think I'm more than happy to respond again